# How to redirect all traffic to https & non-www in web.config?

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config

I'm using an SSL certificate and IIS.  In my web.config I want to redirect all website traffic in the following order:

1. all http --> https
2. all www --> non-www

Comment: Please specify web server you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the answer

```
 <system.webServer>


  <rewrite>
   <rules>
     <clear />

     <rule name="NonWwwRedirect"  stopProcessing="true"> 
    <match url="(.*)" /> 
    <conditions> 
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.yoursit\.com$" /> 
    </conditions> 
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://yoursite.com/{R:1}" /> 
</rule> 
     <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url=".*" />
       <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
       </conditions>
       <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
     </rule>
   </rules>
 </rewrite>
 <system.webServer />
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [redirect module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/) in order to do this.  This intercepts the request as it's coming in to the server and changes it according to your instructions.

Here is an action to redirect all to https:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
```

and here is one to redirect www to non-www:

```
<conditions> <add input=”{HTTP_HOST}” pattern=”^example\.com$” negate=”true” /> </conditions> <action type=”Redirect” url=”http://example.com/{R:1}” />
```

There are plenty of articles around the web and StackOverflow when you include both "web.config" and "redirect" in your search.

Make sure that when you set up the rules you only use `stopProcessing="true"` on the final rule.  If that appears on the first rule then the second rule will never execute.

Comment: i need 2 condition together , please help